# Java swing Exception handler

Tags: java, swing, exception, error-handling, jtextfield

I'm making program that calculates average of added numbers. Program calculate normally, but when I tried to add Exception handler, I failed. When I put numbers, its work fine, but when i submit empty space or other sign, my error message keep pop-up everytime i turn push OK or x . I just want to make that when I make error(submit empty space or other sign) I get popup message with error, push OK, then keep adding new numbers without any calculation bugs.

whole program:

Main

```
package average;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main (String []args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Created by Mac4s");
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(300,220);
                frame.setResizable(true);

                Surface surfObj = new Surface();
                frame.add(surfObj);         
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Surface

```
package average;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class Surface extends JLabel{
    private JTextField numberTxtFld;
    private JLabel topLabel;
    private JLabel sumLabel;
    private JLabel avgLabel;
    private JLabel maxLabel;
    private JLabel minLabel;
    private JLabel amountLabel;
    private JLabel listLabel;
    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private JLabel sumAnswerFld;
    private JLabel avgAnswerFld;
    private JLabel maxAnswerFld;
    private JLabel minAnswerFld;
    private JLabel amountAnswerFld;
    private JLabel fullListLabel;
    private JList fullList;
    final List<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JButton submitBtn;
    private JButton closeBtn;
    private JPanel panel;

    private DefaultListModel defaultListModel;

    private int arrayIndex = 0;// used for components adding into array

    public Surface(){   
        defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setSize(290, 180);

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        topLabel = new JLabel("Enter your number and push submit");
        topLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));

        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0; // column 
        gbc.gridy = 0; // row
        panel.add(topLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1; // setting grid column with to default

        fullListLabel = new JLabel("Full list");
        fullListLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(fullListLabel, gbc);

        resultLabel = new JLabel("Result: ");
        resultLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(resultLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1; // setting grid column with to default

        avgLabel = new JLabel("Average");
        avgLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(avgLabel, gbc);

        sumLabel = new JLabel("Total");
        sumLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(sumLabel, gbc);

        amountLabel = new JLabel("Amount");
        amountLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(amountLabel, gbc);

        maxLabel = new JLabel("Max");
        maxLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(maxLabel, gbc);

        minLabel = new JLabel("Min");
        minLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(minLabel, gbc);

        avgAnswerFld = new JLabel(" 0");
        avgAnswerFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(avgAnswerFld, gbc);

        sumAnswerFld = new JLabel(" 0");
        sumAnswerFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(sumAnswerFld, gbc);

        amountAnswerFld = new JLabel(" 0");
        amountAnswerFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(amountAnswerFld, gbc);

        maxAnswerFld = new JLabel(" 0");
        maxAnswerFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(maxAnswerFld, gbc);

        minAnswerFld = new JLabel(" 0");
        minAnswerFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(minAnswerFld, gbc);

        numberTxtFld = new JTextField();
        numberTxtFld.setColumns(10);
        numberTxtFld.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        gbc.ipady = 10;
        gbc.ipadx = 60;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(numberTxtFld, gbc);

        fullList = new JList(defaultListModel);
        fullList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        fullList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        gbc.gridheight = 6;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(fullList), gbc);
        gbc.gridheight = 1; // setting grid column with to default

        submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        gbc.ipady = 10;
        gbc.ipadx = 10;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        submitBtn.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    boolean error = false;
                    do{
                        try{
                            defaultListModel.clear(); // clear screen and then add new list
                            String text = numberTxtFld.getText();
                            numbersList.add(text);
                            for (Object x : numbersList) {
                                defaultListModel.addElement(x);
                            }   
                            numberTxtFld.setText("");

                            int amount = defaultListModel.getSize(); // amount of added numbers
                            double sum = 0;// total sum of added numbers
                            for (Object x : numbersList) {
                                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt((String) x);
                            }
                            double average = sum / amount; // calculate average number
                            int max = -2147483647; // calculate maximal number
                            for (Object x : numbersList) {
                                if (max <= Integer.parseInt((String) x))
                                    max = Integer.parseInt((String) x);
                            }
                            int min = 2147483647; // calculate min number
                            for (Object x : numbersList) {
                                if (min >= Integer.parseInt((String) x))
                                    min = Integer.parseInt((String) x);
                            }
                            sumAnswerFld.setText(Double.toString(sum));// total sum of added numbers

                            amountAnswerFld.setText(Integer.toString(amount));// amount of added numbers

                            avgAnswerFld.setText(String.format("%.3f", average)); // calculate average number

                            maxAnswerFld.setText(Integer.toString(max));// write maximal

                            minAnswerFld.setText(Integer.toString(min)); // write minimal
                            error = true;
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input, try again" , "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }while(error == false);
                }// action performed end                    
            }// new  action listener end
        );  // submitbtn.action listener end    
        panel.add(submitBtn, gbc);

        add(panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `do-while` loop, in swing, you don't need a loop, it's not like a command line.

Remove this:

```
do{

....} while(error==true);
```

You have a lot of miss around, but corrected your code.

1. Remove `try-catch`
2. Add these few lines to your code:

   ```
   // clear screen and then add new list
   String text = numberTxtFld.getText();
   boolean isNumber = false;
   try{
       Integer.parseInt(text);
       numbersList.add(text);
       isNumber = true;
   } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
       //JOptionPane.show.......
       numberTxtFld.setText("");
   }
   if(isNumber){
   defaultListModel.clear();
   for (Object x : numbersList) 
   //.........
   ```

Comment: Its almost work when I remove it. But all calculations stops after error.

Comment: @MartynasŽukovas That's what you would expect.  As soon as you hit one error, it should stop and ask the user to correct the problem.  Then they should hit the submit button again...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that escapes the dialog popups entirely: Use `JFormattedTextField` instead of `JTextField`. This will automatically take care of input errors. If an invalid value is entered, the invalid value is replaced by the last valid value by default, but this can be changed with `setFocusLostBehavior`. You would construct such a field with a no argument constructor, then call `setValue(new Integer(0))`, then use it. If you need to know the number in the field, you can use `(Integer) getValue()`.